# When I deployed my blog generated with hexo in github, how to post a new article in another computer?

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

I used computer one to generate a blog, and deployed it on my github repository, can I post a new article with another computer? It seems that cloning the repository didn't work cause the blog need hexo to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to setup [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org/) build to generate the blog. Your github repository will containt sources (not the generated output) and trivis ci will run hexo on every commit and push artifacts to github-pages brabch. With this process it will be possible to just push new page source to primary branch (from any computer) and travis will automatically regenerate and deploy.